# How to get stream video(m3u8 format) resolution from url link, android2.3.3?

Tags: android, url, video-streaming, resolution, m3u

I have tried many ways to retrieve the video meta data from url like (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/streams/xxxx/playlist.m3u8), the project is useing android 2.3.3 SDK.

1. As I know the MediaMetadataRetriver can solve it with capture_mode but it needs the android vesion level after 14, but android 2.3.3 is level 10. (it doesnt work in project).

   MediaMetadataRetriever retr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retr.setDataSource(mContext , video.getUriWithDrmCheck());
    retr.setMode(MediaMetadataRetriever.MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY);
    Bitmap bm = retr.captureFrame();
    int wVideo = bm.getWidth();
    int hVideo = bm.getHeight();
2. I have been used vetamio to retrieve the video resolution, but the system crashed. 
   io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer m= new io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer(this);
                       m.prepareAsyc();
           m.setDataSource(url);
           m.getVideoAspectRatio();
                   m.release();
3. The default android.media.mediaplayer in android could not retrieve the url video information.
   The video height I got from it is 0.
4. I tried thumbnail method to retrieve the video information, but the Thumbnail method seems can only phase the localPath, not the url link path.
   Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(url, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

So does any one know how to retrieve a stream video (m3u8 format) resolution from url link in android?? thank you very much.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?